# Save Properties Downloaded from Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring Cloud Config Server/Client and the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) says that the server takes precedence by default over a local application.properties file. If the cloud config server happens to be unavailable the application will retry for some time and then fail to start up correctly. I would like to go around this issue by having the application save the properties fetched from the config server when it starts correctly and therefore when the config server isn't available default to the last set of properties it downloaded. Is this possible? If yes how do I access and save the properties?

Comment: like this: http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/

Comment: The actual configuration file is never on the client machine

Comment: well I asume that you have to create a local propertie-file first. and set it up in your java code. In case your server starts set up the properties how you want. In case it dosen't use the last functionable properties or boot from another propertie file

Comment: I would like to create the local property-file using the properties fetched from the config server but I have no idea hot to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a class that implements `EnvironmentAware` and instantiated it as a spring bean so a property of type `Environement` get set automatically. I then used `environmet.getPropertySources()` to get the properties I needed. I then proceeded to write them to file.

I arrived to this solution by examining the code of Spring's actuator and the `/env` endpoint displays the applications properties.